# Yoga framework giving could not build module Foundation

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

In my native iOS project integrated with react native for a few functionalities. I am getting strange errors while building.

[image]
[image]

[image]

I tried the following steps to fix, but no use

1. Deleting derived data
2. pod deintegrate and pod install
3. Delete and installing node modules
4. pod upgrade
5. Quit xcode and launch again
6. Restarting computer

Could you please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling Xcode everything works fine.